# Adding a Title on popup window center with icon on the right

Tags: css

I want to create a popup window with a title centered and a close icon on the right but I want that the icon don't take place of the centered title

```
<div class="popup-title">
        <div class="span12" style="vertical-align: middle">MyTitle
            <span class="icon-close-popup" style="vertical-align: middle" ></span>    
        </div>           
    </div>
```

The problem is that the icon is part of the div and if I move the icon with margen-right, it will move the title as well and will not be centered anymmore.
How can I keep the text centered independent of the icon on the right?

Comment: Hello, some example of your css?

Comment: I don't have a css because I don't know how to do it